# A Wirtinger-like inequality involving two functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, inequalities

Let $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ be periodic functions on $t\in[0,2\pi]$. By using the Fourier series of the two functions, we can easily prove the inequality
$$\left|\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)g'(t)dt\right|=
  \left|\int_0^{2\pi}f'(t)g(t)dt\right|\le
  \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}[f'(t)^2+g'(t)^2]dt\text.$$

I have been trying to find a reference for this inequality because I need to use it to solve some problem. The closest I have been able to find is [Pachpatte 1986](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X86902283), which gives
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\left[|f(t)||g'(t)|+|f'(t)||g(t)|\right]dt\le
\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}[f'(t)^2+g'(t)^2]dt\text.$$

The extra factor of $\pi$ is highly undesirable and the absolute values inside of
the integral unnecessary for me. I can easily provide a short proof in the text,
but if anybody can think of where the first inequality might appear, that would
be better.

Comment: I think there must be a mistake in the second inequality, since $f=c$ and $|g^\prime|=1$ would give the inequality $c \leq \pi$.  

The first inequality is an easier inequality from this perspective, and is provable by using a standard Poincare inequality for

$||f-\overline{f}||_{L^2}\leq C ||f^\prime||_{L^2}$ with the optimal constant $C$ and realizing that you can introduce the average value on the left hand side, due to periodicity of $g$, followed by Cauchy-Schwartz.

Comment: Oh yeah. The second inequality has more assumptions that I forgot to include $f(0)=g(0)=0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your inequality is implicit in Hurwitz's Fourier series proof of the isoperimetric inequality in the plane.  See for example section 36 of Körner's *Fourier Analysis* or section 4.1 of Groemer's *Geometric Applications of Fourier Series and Spherical Harmonics*.